# gulp files aren't refresh in browser

Tags: backbone.js, gulp

I have a problem with gulp file on my *Backbone* project. I'm working on a project with two other peoples. With them everything is working. I have a problem with browser cache - I think is with browser cache.

How it looks:
When I made changes gulp watch doesn't return any errors. Gulp copies all files from the src to dist folder. I've checked my files and they are saving correctly.

I turned off *browser cache* in the developer toolbar and it won't help. Sometimes I need to wait few minutes before I see my changes, and sometimes I need to refresh 20-30 times to see changes I've made.

Many time I see in console this error:

> router.js:22 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

When I debug this file I see that this file is incomplete but when open this file in browser directly - it is complete but still console shows an error

What else can I do, because I can't work like this?

Comment: of course many time I see in console this error:
`router.js:22 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`
when I debug this file I see that this file is incomplete but when open this file in browser directly - it is complete but still console shows an error

Comment: The problem could be with source maps code in gulp. comment the sourcemaps related code and check once.

Comment: I've had this problem too, nowadays I use [browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp) and I never run into this issue anymore.